# How can export Bigquery table with spesific row count

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, export-to-csv

I've exported bigquery table as a csv file into a bucket using this:

```
EXPORT DATA
 OPTIONS (
  uri = 'gs://export/test/*.csv',
  format = 'csv'
  overwrite = true
)
AS (
select * from table 
);
```

And It is exported as several files on the bucket, that's nice beacuse I use these files for some computanioal processes and It provides parallelism. But still file size are kinda big and I want to spesifty a limit for row count for each file. Is there any way to do that?

Is there a solution for file size limit in gcp doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#control_the_exported_file_size but it requires temp table to partion process

Comment: You can omit the temps table but it will be more expensive. The trick here is to perform an export data statement for each "partition" (or chunk). Do it on a partitioned table, or do it on the fly. As you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @guillaume blaquiere mentioned in the comments:

You can omit the temps table **but it will be more expensive**. The trick here is to perform an `export data` statement for each **"partition"** (or chunk). Do it on a partitioned table, or do it on the fly. As you wish.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* as this is the **BEST PRACTICE** and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.